# cannot call function in backend controller from front end controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I have a peculiar problem and I cannot locate any solution for this, can someone please guide me here.
I have a website which works perfectly on my webhosting, but when i downloaded it on my local server and hosting it on xampp server i get a very weird error 
It cannot locate a function in my controller when i make a call to redirect.

below is the code from this class

```
class Site extends FrontendController {
 .
 .
 .
 .
  public function login(){
    if( !empty( $_POST['Login'] ) ){

            /* user has submitted login information */

            $this->cuseridentity->init( $_POST['Login']['user_name'], $_POST['Login']['password'] );
            if( $this->cuseridentity->authenticate() && $this->cuseridentity->login() ){
                /* user was able to login */
                switch( $this->cuseridentity->get_data( 'role' ) ){
                    case 'admin':
                        redirect ( 'admin/product/index' ) ; //This is not working
                    break;
                    case 'counter': 
                        redirect( 'store/index' ); // this works
                    break;
                    case 'user': //invcounter
                        redirect( 'invcounter/dashboard/index' ) ; //( this does not work'gallery' ); 
                    break;
                    default :
                        redirect( 'gallery ') ; //this works 
                    break;
                }
            }

    }
    $this->load->view( 'site/login' );

}

This is in my routes file 
$route['default_controller'] = 'store/index';
$route['login'] = 'site/login';
$route['login/(:any)'] = 'site/login/$1';  
$route['index'] = 'store/index';
$route['productindex'] = 'admin/product/productindex' ;
//$route['product/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'store/product/$1/$2';  
$route['product_detail/(:any)'] = 'store/prod_detail/$1';   
$route['statue_detail/(:any)'] = 'store/statue_detail/$1';   
$route['statues'] = 'store/statues';
$route['aboutus'] = 'store/aboutus';  
$route['product'] = 'admin/product';
//$route['product'] = 'store/product';
$route['customer_profile'] = 'store/customer_profile';
$route['gallery'] = 'store/gallery';
$route['contactus'] = 'store/contactus';
$route['event'] = 'store/event';
$route['landingpage'] = 'store/landingpage';
$route['place_order'] = 'store/place_order';
$route['blogs'] = 'store/blogs';
$route['concept'] = 'store/concept';
$route['disclaimer'] = 'store/disclaimer';
$route['concept'] = 'store/concept';
$route['policies'] = 'store/policies';
$route['termcondition'] = '/store/termcondition';
$route['logout1'] = 'store/logout';
$route['blogdetail'] = 'store/blogdetail';   
$route['logout'] = 'site/logout'; 
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

When i try to login here on localhost i keep getting error

```
An Error Was Encountered

Requested function not found : index
```

[this is the directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnQb7.jpg)

Any help in any direction that can be given will be appreciated.

Comment: what version is the `codeigniter`? have you checked the routes? the controller methods for those failing?

Comment: Let see your `.htaccess`. Have you set up `mod_rewrite` in xamp?

Comment: have you check the config/config.php base_url() setting?

Comment: @bagus Tesa I am not sure about the version, the original tech team has abandoned the project and now its fallen in my lap.

Comment: @Kisaragi the .htaccess file has this 
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /
# Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
i am new to xampp, i have worked on other webservers but not very sure about xampp, where do i setup mod_rewrite?

Comment: @GilangPratama The base url setting in config.php is 
$path = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); 
$config['base_url'] = $path; .
please note the website is working perfectly fine on the server. Its just when i downloaded it to my local pc and installed xampp to run this website that i am getting this problem. This is only when i am trying to connect to the admin part of the site from where we can customize the website.

Comment: what is your localhost? xampp? or another localhost?

Comment: the localhost is xampp.

Comment: I'm sorry too late to reply this comment. you can try to write
`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project/';`